# Get the Day name of Long text mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am a beginner I am trying to get the name of the day of a long text using query below but I am getting null d1 column is long text.

```
d1 = day/mm/yyyy
ex d1 = 01/11/2018
```

Desired Output is Thursday since 01 of nov is thursday. I will really appreciate any advice or help thank you

```
SELECT  DAYNAME(d1) FROM tbl1
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: giving me null result

Answer (score 1):

Get the date into a format that the DB recognizes:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select DAYNAME('2018-01-11');
+-----------------------+
| DAYNAME('2018-01-11') |
+-----------------------+
| Thursday              |
+-----------------------+
```

From your long text, you could even do this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select DAYNAME(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01/11/2018', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DAYNAME(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01/11/2018', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Thursday                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Replace the slashed-date portion with your d1 column:

```
select DAYNAME(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(d1, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'));
```

...should work as well, assuming the column is `d1`.

=====

Based on Nick's suggested format, you can eliminate the use of `DAYNAME`:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01/11/2018', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%W');
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01/11/2018', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%W') |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Thursday                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: No need to use `DAYNAME(DATE_FORMAT(..., '%Y-%m-%d'))` just use `DATE_FORMAT(..., '%W')`

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Added an example with your `%W` format tip to the answer.